# Rails|Slim : Assign new local variables in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have a local variable in a view @people, it is possible to assign an association of the local variable to another one.

```
-@people.interactions = @interactions
```

I tried this but it did not work, is there a way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- interactions = @people.interactions
= interactions
```

The slim so you can assign a value to a variable:

```
- my_text = my_value
```

And so their output:

```
p
  = my_text
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you put it in the controller to keep your code neat. but if you really need this you can use global variable

```
- $interactions = @people.interactions
```

and then you can call this in models controllers or views